# Vue.js - How to fetch JSON data object by object?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a big JSON file (40 MB) that contains information about countries, their ids and finally a sum that I need to get its total.

```
{
        "0": {
                "id": 0,
                "country": "usa",
                "sum": 201,
        },
        "1": {
                "id": 1,
                "country": "fr",
                "sum": 133,

        }
}
```

When I try to fetch this data into a variable it works good but consumes so much memory, so I want to read these country objects' only sum field and then calculate the total sum. How can I do that?

I'm using following code to get the whole JSON:

```
fetch(fetchURL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJSON => {
        this.json_data = responseJSON;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

`responseJSON.sum` does not work, I think it requires index but I couldn't do it in the fetch.

Comment: "When I try to fetch this data into a variable it works good but consumes so much memory" I think you should this from the backend.

Comment: Do the summing server side.

Comment: did you try my answer ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, yes. Thank you very much, I think it has same efficiency with the solution I marked, right?

Comment: yes i know but i recommend to use functions like `map`, `reduce` and `forEach` when you work with arrays instead of loops using `for`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Oh, alright then I'd better to use reduce instead of for. Is there are performance differences or is it a common programming style to handle with these issues?

Comment: these functions are made by experts in JS so they are more performant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES6, you can simply do the following:

```
 fetch(fetchURL)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJSON => {
            var sum = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(responseJSON).length; i++) {
              sum += responseJSON[i]['sum'];
            }
            console.log(sum); // This is the total sum
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: It does make sense and it is actually a solution for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure to fully understand what you want to do: either get an array with only the `sum` property because your `responseJSON` is too big, or get the actual sum of all the `sum` variables.

Here is a portion of code that might help :

```
var countries = [
 {
   "id": 0,
   "country": "usa",
   "sum": 201,
 },
 {
   "id": 1,
   "country": "fr",
   "sum": 133,
 }
];

var totalSum = 0;

var sumArray = countries.map(function(country) {
  totalSum = totalSum + country.sum;
  return country.sum;
});
```

In this portion of code, I am using the javascript map function to get an array with all the `sum` variables in it. I am also making the total sum of the `sum` variables with the `totalSum` variable.

If you just need to get the total sum of the `sum` variables, I would rather recommend to use the `forEach` javascript function rather than the `map` function.

Hope this might help...

Comment: What you have done is exactly what I want to do but I try to make it while fetching the json

Answer (score 1):

You could do it simply using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function as follows

```
 fetch(fetchURL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJSON => {
    const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator.sum + currentValue.sum;
        let sum =Object.values(responseJSON).reduce(reducer);

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

**Example**

```js
let arr = {
  "0": {
    "id": 0,
    "country": "usa",
    "sum": 201,
  },
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "country": "fr",
    "sum": 133,

  }
}

const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator.sum + currentValue.sum;
let sum = Object.values(arr).reduce(reducer);

console.log(sum)
```